# SQLite in Native Client

Tags: sqlite, google-nativeclient

I am trying to use `sqlite3` in a Native Client application. There is a port available in the Chromium project, but I was unable to make it run properly.
My problem is that, for some reason, the application is unable to open a DB since a call like `sqlite3_open("/filename.db", &db);` fails with an I/O error.
I mounted `/` to a `html5fs` file system.

Has anybody managed to use SQLite with Native Client?
If so, I would really like to see a simple code that does something like opening a DB, `CREATE` a table, `INSERT` something and do a `SELECT`.

Answer (score 2):

Struggled for almost a day, I found a workaround to skip the disk I/O error with specifying a VFS parameter.

```
sqlite3_open_v2(filename, &db, SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE | SQLITE_OPEN_CREATE | SQLITE_OPEN_NOMUTEX, "unix-none");
```

For more information about VFS, please see http://www.sqlite.org/vfs.html
My testing environment is on a chrome extension.